# Cloud Functions 400 Bad Request with invalid JSON in hello world app

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I have hello world cloud functions app, it's working fine either locally by **firebase serve** or online after **firebase deploy**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Locally I can open http://localhost:5000/testing-98b0b/us-central1/helloWorld without any issues, but if I use postman to send post call with an invalid body like "#" it crashes and keep loading with below error:

[image]

```
error: { SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  expose: true,
  statusCode: 400,
  status: 400,
  body: '#',
  type: 'entity.parse.failed' }
```

Also after **firebase deploy** I can open 
https://us-central1-staff-testing-98b0b.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld 
without any issues but if I use postman to send post call with an invalid body like "#" it crashes and returns 400 bad request with below error:

[image]

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /var/tmp/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
```

Is it bug in the firebase-functions library? Is there any way to handle this type of invalid requests?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: @DougStevenson if we do the same post-man call with express hello world app .. it handles it without any crashes or at least we have the availability to handle that manually. I am asking this question because we have online nodejs app up and runnin. and we do receive many calls like that, and we are going to migrate to cloud-functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "handles it"?  If the request is invalid, why wouldn't the function generate 400?  That's the very definition of a 400 type error.

Comment: Consider also that maybe the emulator response is the one that's not correct, and that the emulator isn't a 100% exact replica for deployed Cloud Functions.

Comment: I mean if I can catch that case and return json with bad request message..

Comment: If the client is telling the server that it's going to send Json in a header, then sends something else, seems like system isn't going to let you step in and reverse the decision

Comment: So, if I have tons of invalid calls on a daily basis, my error panel will contain tons of errors everyday https://www.screencast.com/t/VPpC2Rm0 Is there any way to clean it to track other errors?